# Rewriting a URL only if a filetype is not specified in the request

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am currently using the following .htaccess on a site:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) /home [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It works fine, and redirects URLs such as `www.test.com/page2` to `www.test.com/page2.php`.

However, I have a couple of files I would like site users to be able to download, and I've just realised that the rewrite rules are changing requests like `page2/file.pdf` to `page2/file.pdf.php`, which of course returns a 404.

How can I modify the rules to request a `.php` file only if another filetype hasn't been specified in the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your rules slighty so that it checks to see if the php file exists before rewriting it. If it's not a php file, it won't rewrite. Try these rules.

```
RewriteEngine on

#ignore real files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#redirect root to /home
RewriteRule ^/?$ /home [R=301,L]

#check if php file exists and rewrite to file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: This is great, and does the job, thanks! The only thing is that it now allows direct browsing of the file structure if a the path entered is a directory. Is it possible to prevent this?

Comment: That is handled by indexing. Add `Options -Indexes` to the top of the htaccess file. Also if this works for you please accept answer.